# What is the fastest method to solve this 5-digit summation problem?

Tags: summation

Consider the following 3 totals:

```
65,232
73,002
56,273
```

For each total listed above, identify the three numbers from the following list which, when summed up, equal each total above.

```
41,207
33,749
27,641
25,921
24,790
20,348
18,905
18,686
12,797
11,447
```

There are 10*9*8 (720) possibilities - what is the fastest way to identify the three numbers for each total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of possibilities is actually much lower, only $\frac{10\times9\times8}{3\times2\times1} = 120$, because it doesn't matter what order they come in; however, we can do some things to reduce the amount of work required: we can calculate the required smallest value based on the larger two values, and we can restrict the possible range of the larger values based on their order.

First things first: We know that the largest of the three numbers must be higher than $1/3$ the size of the target number.  For $65\,232$ this means that we only need to check the first $5$ numbers for that, because anything smaller than $65\,232 / 3 = 21\,744$ can't possibly the largest number.

Now, considering each of these numbers in turn, we'll try $a = 41\,207$ and find the leftovers $65\,232-41\,207 = 24\,025$.  The second number, $b$, must be smaller than this; it must also be smaller than $a$ itself, and furthermore it must be small enough that $c$ can possibly be on the list, that is to say $b < x-a-\min(pile)$.  The second number must also be larger than half of these leftovers so it's larger than whatever $c$ ends up being, which means $\frac{x-a}{2} < b < \min(a,x-a-\min(pile))$, that is, $12\,012.5\le b < 12\,578$.  There are actually no candidates for $b$ that work for this $a$!  The first one that meets these requirements is $a=33\,749$ and $b=18\,905$.

Finally, we don't need to *try* values for $c$; we can simply calculate $c=x-a-b$ and see if that's in the list.  From $120$ things to check we've gone down to just $9$, and the answer is $33\,749+18\,686+12\,797=65\,232$.

Similar work will do the job very quickly for the other two values: there are $9$ candidates for $73\,002$ and only $6$ for $56\,273$.

---

We can generalize this:

To find a subset of size $n$ in a set $S$ of non-negative numbers that adds to a value $x$:

Then $a_k$, the $k$th highest value, must be at least $\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}a_j}{n-k-1}$, and at most the minimum of $a_{k-1}$ and $x - \sum_{j=1}^{n-k}S_j$, where $S$ is in order from lowest to highest.  Iterate, depth-first, available values for $a_k$; upon reaching $a_n$ the above bounds converge on a single value, and if that's in $S$ then you win.